# Where do I get Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management.dll?

Tags: .net, windows, group-policy, infrastructure

Having a look at this code
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee862406%28VS.85%29.aspx

It says "Add the Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management assembly to your project" but i cant seem to find out where to get Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management from.

Comment: good question! And they should specify where these dll files reside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182374%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Will.
I actually already had that installed. So i did a full search of my system and found the assembly here C:\Windows\winsxs\msil_microsoft.grouppolicy.management_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_9af1a716fa553d25
thanks for your help

Comment: So write your as the answer @Simon

Comment: @saher but "i already had it installed" does not answer the question.